# Select one cell in each sheet to put it in another sheet

Tags: vba

I am currently building a macro for Excel in order to read hundreds of txt files. For now everything work well and each txt file has its sheet.

I would like to take the value of a precise cell in each sheet (that would always be at the same place) and put it in a created sheet.

It is the value of the cell that I can't get to work, because I don't know how to say in VBA "this cell equal the value of this cell in this sheet, without any R[]C[]."

The naming of the sheets is precise and in function of a concatenated loop of 3 parameters.

Here is what i have done (the sheet result is created at the begining) :

```
'###loops k, j, i
ActiveSheet.Name = querie 'querie =k & j & i basically

Sheets("Results").Select
Range("A" & j - 1 & i).Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "= querie & "!" & "M1""

Next i
Next j
Next k
```

Hope it is clear,
Thanks a lot !

Comment: So what's the problem with your code? You need to ask a specific question.

Comment: `Sheets("Results").Range("A" & j - 1 & i).Formula = "='" & querie & "'!M1""`   Not sure about that `Range("A" & j - 1 & i)` though?

Comment: Well, my question is : how to take a cell from each sheet and put it in a specific sheet "result"

Comment: Thanks Tim for the help, , but this doesn't work, applicattion defined error ?